# cannot access /wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install after installing 5.28.3

Tags: wordpress, installation

I have found it impossible to upgrade from CiviCRM 5.25 to 5.28 to get around the breakage caused by the WP upgrade from 5.4 to 5.5

My attempted solution has been to make a staging site, completely remove civiCRM and reinstall using the 5.28.3 zip file.
All seems to go well including adding the UK i10n files until I go to
***/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install***

Where I get the message **Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.**

As the only admin on the site, I find this strange.   Any hints?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I want to have a staging copy of CIVICRM on my WordPress server. For that purpose, I have started from my live CIVICRM implementation and created a "staging" copy of CIVICRM on a separate directory. First issue was to resolve a database connection issue. I have looked in many posts to resolve a database connection issue and ended up deleting the wp-content/plugins/civicrm folders and the wp-contend/uploads/civicrm folders. I unzipped a fresh copy of civicrm 5.50 in the wp-content/plugins folder.
From the WP administrator panel I activated the civicrm plugin. I have a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is CiviCRM already installed?
Even if the DB is clean, does the `wp-content/uploads/civicrm` folder exist with the `civicrm.settings.php` file in it.  The installer does not expect that to be there.

You shouldn't hit the install page on an upgrade.  I'd expect you to go to http://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1

Full docs are at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/

Comment: I deleted the old civicrm and created a new structure in plugins. However on checking uploads I see I have a civicrm folder still there . I will delete that and try again - thank you

Comment: That seems to have done the trick - now I need to set up the cron job and configure a default mailbox etc etc   

Many thanks